# node.js install modules still loading without any result

Tags: node.js, npm

I just want to install modules in folder on desktop
its still loading forever

in first time its work and install the modules but after thats its never install any modules

> npm install express-generator -g
>
> npm install   .... I have package in same folder

[image]

its still like this see image

I uninstall it and install it again same problem also I uninstall it and download new 32 bit and same problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found the answer here

i just use this command

> npm config set loglevel info
>
> npm cache add xxx.tgz

http://www.eguidedog.net/doc/what-to-do-when-npm-install-hangs.php